# MATLAB ksdensity equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I've looked online and have yet to find an answer or way to figure the following

I'm translating some MATLAB code to Python where in MATLAB im looking to find the kernel density estimation with the function:

```
[p,x] = ksdensity(data)
```

where p is the probability at point x in the distribution.

Scipy has a function but only returns p.

Is there a way to find the probability at values of x?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That form of the `ksdensity` call automatically generates an arbitrary `x`. `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde()` returns a callable function that can be evaluated with any `x` of your choosing. The equivalent `x` would be `np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 100)`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = ...
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
x = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 100)
p = kde(x)
```

Comment: Just for a quick reference, I tried both `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde()` and `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`, the first I got `kernel dead`, and the second works.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is the kernel density estimator in the Scikit-Learn Python package, [sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity)

Here is a little example similar to the Matlab documentation for ksdensity for a Gaussian distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

np.random.seed(12345)
# similar to MATLAB ksdensity example x = [randn(30,1); 5+randn(30,1)];
Vecvalues=np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0,1,30), np.random.normal(5,1,30)))[:,None]
Vecpoints=np.linspace(-8,12,100)[:,None]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(Vecvalues)
logkde = kde.score_samples(Vecpoints)
plt.plot(Vecpoints,np.exp(logkde))
plt.show()
```

The plot this produces looks like:

[image]

Comment: Matlab is orders of magnitude faster than KernelDensity when it comes to finding the optimal bandwidth. Any idea of how to make the KernelDenisty faster?

Answer (score 1):

> Matlab is orders of magnitude faster than KernelDensity when it comes to finding the optimal bandwidth. Any idea of how to make the KernelDenisty faster? – Yuca Jul 16 '18 at 20:58

Hi, Yuca. The matlab use [Scott rule](https://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232493-ksdensity-default-bandwidth-value#) to estimate the bandwidth, which is fast but requires the data from the normal distribution. For more information, please see this [Post](https://aakinshin.net/posts/kde-bw/).